# Changing zero to x in multidimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 3-dimensional array in python, and would like to learn how to find and replace given elements

For example,

```
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 5, 0, 1], [2, 1, 3, 10]], np.int32)
```

I'd like to replace each 0 with x in the array, which would result in:

```
([[1,1,1,x], [x,5,x,1], [2,1,3,10]])
```

This is where I am at, but I get an error due to 'x' not being an integer

import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,1,1,0],[0,5,0,1],[2,1,3,10]])
x[x==0] = 'x'
print (x)

Answer (score 2):

Can do something like:

```
x[x==0] = 10
```

Comment: Does this work for strings or letters? I am trying to get an array to assess 'X' as an integer. So in a perfect scenario this would work x[x==0] = 'x'

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
In [4]: y = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 5, 0, 1], [2, 1, 3, 10]], np.int32)

In [5]: y[y == 0] = 9999

In [6]: y
Out[6]:
array([[   1,    1,    1, 9999],
       [9999,    5, 9999,    1],
       [   2,    1,    3,   10]])
```

Comment: Thank you chris! can numpy boolean array indexing transfer integers to strings (I think I have that lingo right, but I am brand new to coding). In example, I am trying to do something like this: y[y == 0] = 'x'.